# How get ESSID and Access Point when I write iwconfig

Tags: linux, python-2.7, networking

I write iwconfig so I can have he name of my lan ESSID and mac of point acess ,I want to recover his two fields for using in a script I can be on the first line, but I can not have the information that I want.

how to ubuntu I vaoir that valeus ESSID and Access Point

wlan0 IEEE 802.11bgn ESSID:"Home"
Mode:Managed Frequency:2.437 GHz Access Point: 00:03:B6:K9:L1:9E

I need help. thanks.

try:

```
  proc = Popen(['iwconfig'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=DN)
  print "try de iwconfig %s"%proc
```

except OSError:

```
  sys.exit("Could not execute iwconfig")
```

for line in proc.communicate()[0].split('\n'): print "line %s"%line if len(line) == 0:

```
           continue # Isn't an empty string

    if line[0] != ' ': 

              if 'IEEE 802.11' in line:

                   if "ESSID:\"" in line:

                           print line[ESSID][0]
                    if "Access Point:\"" in line:
                           print line[Access Point][0]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For my output of `iwconfig`, a regex like this seems to work perfectly fine:

```
from re import *
from subprocess import *

proc = Popen(['iwconfig'], stdout=PIPE)
intext=str(proc.communicate()[0])
m1=search('Access Point: [ABCDEF0123456789:]*',intext)
AP=m1.group(0).split(' ')[2]
print AP

m2=search('ESSID:".*" ',intext)
ESSID=m2.group(0).split('"')[1]
print ESSID
```